# Empty graph in fgl library

Tags: haskell

I have tried to generate empty graph with `String` nodes and unlabelled edges as follows,

```
λ> let emptyGraph = empty :: Graph gr => gr String ()
λ> emptyGraph
emptyGraph :: Graph gr => gr String ()
λ> isEmpty emptyGraph
Ambiguous type variable ‘gr0’ arising from a use of ‘isEmpty’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Graph gr0)’ from being solved.
```

I get same error with `isEmpty empty`, am I specifying its type correctly?

Also why is `gr` in the type signature is a lower case instead of expected capital letter for data type names?

Link to [fgl library](https://github.com/haskell/fgl/)

Comment: Looking at the documentation in hackage, the library implements two different `Graph` types: `Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` and `Data.Graph.Inductive.Tree`. Every function has signature `Graph gr => ...` meaning that you have to specify the actual implementation, otherwise GHC will not know which one pick. Solution: `let emptyGraph = empty :: Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree.Gr String ()`. You can also `import Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Type classes vs datatypes

As I understand it, type classes are not themselves datatypes and, as such, have no real values associated with them.

Here's what I mean by that. A typeclass always has at least one type variable. When you write `instance Num Int`, you say that if a datatype has the constraint `Num a => a`, you can use `Int` in place of `a`.

Datatypes implement the methods of type classes and then you can use these methods polymorphically on any of those datatypes. `+` is a method for the `Num` typeclass. `Int` and `Double` both have `Num` instances. That's why `2 + 2`* and `3.14 + 3.14` both work.

So when GHC tells you it's found an ambiguous type variable, it means that it knows a bunch of datatypes that implement the constraint `Graph a`, but it doesn't know which one to use. To bring it back to `Num`, if you had `foo :: Num a => a` (assume it has a valid definition) and tried to do `foo + foo`, GHC wouldn't know whether to use the `+` defined for `Int` or `Double` or any other datatype implementing `Num`.

Bearing this in mind…

## The answer

You should be able to resolve your problem by picking a specific graph instance, like `Tree`.

## Technicalities

In many cases when you have an ambiguous type variable, you might think it doesn't matter if GHC just picked *some* datatype that implements
the class. In brief, it sometimes does. GHC and GHCi both implement type defaulting (see e.g. [section 2.4.8](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html)), but they do it differently. GHCi in general tries to default types more aggressively than GHC.

* Technically when you write a literal like `2`, it doesn't need to be of type `Int`. It *technically* is of type `Num a => a` and GHC tries to resolve its type throughout type inference. If it doesn't resolve the, it defaults its type I believe to `Integer`.